# Difference in using LaunchImages and LaunchScreen

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, splash-screen, launchimage

I am working in xamarin ios. I found a difference between using LaunchImages from Assets and using LaunchScreen. When I use LaunchImages I feel that the UI gets little zoomed. But if I use LaunchScreen then its look fine.

Why this is happening? And what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your UI looks little zoomed when using launchimages, *its because lanch image with proper size is not added for specific devices* in a **launchImage** asset of **image.xcimageasset** section.

It will work if you add a proper image for the specific device

[image]

launch Image size guideline provided by apple are like given below:
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

LaunchScreen is the storyboard specially provided to setup your Launch Screen.

> In LaunchScreen you can set the proper constraints and thus show the image with proper layout in every iOS Devices, if proper constraints applied.

Hope it helps.